# Javascript Regex capture group with at least 1 non-digit of two forms: delimited by space and enclosed in quotes

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I'm trying to category_id for purely numeric values, this works. I need to also capture category_name. For category_name, I need to capture until space or include space if it started with a double quote.

Sample user input string:

```
python c:192 c:1Stackoverflow c:"Stack Overflow2"
```

The desired captures should be these two values for category_name and the 192 for category_id.

Expected output:

```
1Stackoverflow
Stack Overflow2
```

The category_name must contain at least one non-digit, but can be all alpha with no digits.

This [query partially works](https://regex101.com/r/rubFNi/1):

```js
/c:(?<category_name>(?:")(?!\d+)[^"]+(?:")|(?!\d+)[^ ]+)/g
```

It doesn't capture the input `1Stackoverflow`, but does the quoted one. I need to remove the quotes:

```js
(x.groups?.[key] ?? '').replace(/^\"/, '').replace(/\"$/, '')
```

The `?!\d+` is an attempt to evade clashing with category_id, but does not appear to be working.

**How can I capture category_name in both forms (one word and quote deliminated) without the quotes in the capture and working with a leading digit?**

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/wWt97z/1

Comment: @code It's all in one group, though. They wish to capture numeric and string values in different groups.

Comment: @code yes but I need the capture names. Category_id for the 192 and Category_name for the other two.

Comment: @kemicofaghost sorry, it was in there I just forgot to code format the expected output. Fixed the formatting

Comment: To capture all 3 named groups in one regex use: `/c:(?:(?<category_id>\d+\b)|(?<category_name>\w+|"[^"]*"))/g`

Comment: My ugly attempt: https://regex101.com/r/SyRGTw/1

Comment: Do you actually have two `category_name` items in a string? If so, how do you want to capture them in a single named group? Or single one, like `python c:192 c:1Stackoverflow` or `python c:192 c:"Stack Overflow2"`?

Comment: @PeterThoeny I do. Generally it makes for better shorthand, so like if I wanted to get “Dungeons & Dragons: Players Handbook” I can do \@Dun \@Pla and both will be captured for group name looking for groups that match both. The \ is so stack doesn’t think I’m at-ing someone named Dun or Pla- users would just do the at symbol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To capture all 3 named groups in one regex use:

```bash
c:(?:(?<category_id>\d+\b)|("?)(?<category_name>(?:[^"\s]+|[^"]+))\2)
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rubFNi/4)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `c:`: Match `c:`
- `(?:`: Start non-capture group

  - `(?<category_id>\d+\b)`: Named capture group `category_id` to match 1+ digits followed by a word boundary
  - `|`: OR
  - `("?)`: Match `"` or empty string and capture in group #2
  - `(?<category_name>[^"\s]+|[^"]+)`: Named capture group `category_name` to match 1+ non-whitespace and non-double quote characters or 1+ of any char that is not a double quote
  - `\2`: Match same text as what we've capture in group #2 which is a `"` or empty string
- `)`: End non-capture group

Comment: @JamesRisner: I have updated my regex and demo. It will capture text between `"`s in `category_name` now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the quotes immediately, I would suggest to use two different named groups for category_name with and without quotes:

```text
c:(?:(?<category_name_q>"[^"]+")|(?<category_name>(?:\d*[a-zA-Z]+)))
```

(category_name_q contains the previously quoted matches, but without quotes)

Comment: Yep captures make the code more difficult with how I’m using these capture groups. I don’t have a limit and the use of more than one is to narrow the results.